# how to include autohint for codeigniter function in netbeans IDE

Tags: codeigniter, netbeans-7, phpdoc

I was able to integrate the codeigniter functions with the netbeans autocomplete feature.

I  was looking for a way so that the user doc can also be integrated with the netbeans so that a small description of the codeigniter function also comes along with the list of the codeigniter function with the auto complete feature. Any suggestions?

There is an option to include phpdoc path in netbeans, but I googled I did not find **phpdoc** of codeigniter. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked this out and I think the problem may be related to the way the CodeIgniter functions are declared. Each function is encapsulated in an:

```
if ( ! function_exists('the_function_name'))
{
    function the_function_name($param)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

When I removed this the autocomplete seemed to work properly (with the description, as well as the parameters). I'm not suggesting that you remove these to solve the problem (as that would involve hacking the CI core) but it may be a limitation in the way Netbeans manages the autocomplete with the way CI functions are declared.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the @property above the classes. You will have autocomplete for your own models and librarys.

See http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/netbeans/netbeans-autocomplete-on-class-properties-using-phpdoc/ for more information about the @property

The problem is you need to do this for all your models in each file. I don't know if this works for the system librarys.